# Create a simple GUI from scratch

Tags: algorithm, conceptual-model

On a platform that has no real libraries available, and bare-minimum graphics other than a "display object of dimension(x,y,xx,yy) at coordinates (x,y),  I'm trying to create a simple gui.

Can someone point me to a reference where I can understand the logistical principles involved in displaying a set of objects on the screen, and highlighting the selected object, allowing users to navigate between objects and move highlighting to each object. It seems like it should be simple to do, but I would like to understand how people think about this.

How would one create an object with a method like obj.highlight() where obj.highlight would turn off highlighting in all other objects? Would one simply do a for next loop through an array of objects, skipping the current object, turning off highlighting and then set the current object to true? Highlighting would be accomplished by drawing another object on top of the selected object with a transparent center.

This is a single threaded system, (but allows a small amount of async processing).

I'm looking more for conceptual ideas but code in VB that doesn't make use of proprietary graphics calls might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I've coded a small sample app that does its own control framework by painting over a form using .Net C#. Just something simple with this result:

[image]

I've done the IsSelected by recursively disabling all controls and toggling the clicked one.
See the part with `window.MouseUp += (sender, arg) =>`.

Selection can go through mouse or the Tab key.

The code approach should be portable to other languages, and online-translatable to VB.Net.

**Relevant snippet of code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form window = new Form1();
            window.BackColor = Color.Gray;

            Graphics api = window.CreateGraphics();

            GUIControl form = new GUIControl();
            form.Location = new Point(30,30);
            form.Size = new Size(200, 300);

            GUIControl control1 = new GUIControl();
            control1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            control1.Size = new Size(200, 130);
            control1.Background = Color.Blue;

            GUIControl control11 = new GUIControl();
            control11.Location = new Point(140, 30);
            control11.Size = new Size(30, 30);
            control11.Background = Color.Red;

            GUIControl control12 = new GUIControl();
            control12.Location = new Point(30, 30);
            control12.Size = new Size(30, 30);
            control12.Background = Color.Red;
            control12.BorderColor = Color.Green;
            control12.BorderWidth = 5;

            GuiLabel control2 = new GuiLabel();
            control2.Location = new Point(10, 200);
            control2.Size = new Size(180, 30);
            control2.Background = Color.Green;
            control2.Text = "Hello World!";

            control1.AddChild(control11);
            control1.AddChild(control12);

            form.AddChild(control1);
            form.AddChild(control2);

            window.MouseUp += (sender, arg) =>
            {
                // hit test the control where the mouse has landed
                IGUIContainer control = form.HitTest(arg.Location);
                if (control != null)
                {
                    // recursive on all controls
                    foreach (var ct in (new IGUIContainer[] { form }).Traverse(c => c.Controls))
                    {
                        //deselecting all others
                        if (ct != control) ct.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                    control.IsSelected = !control.IsSelected;
                }
                window.Invalidate(); // force paint
            };

            window.KeyUp += (sender, key) =>
            {
                if (key.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && key.Modifiers == Keys.None)
                {
                    var selected = (new IGUIContainer[] { form }).Traverse(c => c.Controls).FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsSelected);

                    IGUIContainer parent;

                    if (selected == null)
                    {
                        parent = form;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent = selected;
                    }

                    IGUIContainer control;

                    if (parent.Controls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        control = parent.Controls[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        control = GUIControl.Next(parent);
                    }

                    if (control == null) control = form;

                    foreach (var ct in (new IGUIContainer[] { form }).Traverse(c => c.Controls))
                    {
                        if (ct != control) ct.IsSelected = false;
                    }

                    control.IsSelected = true;

                    window.Invalidate();
                }
            };

            window.Paint += (sender, args) =>
            {
                form.Draw(api, new Point(0,0));
            };

            Application.Run(window);
        }
    }
}
```

**All the needed classes and interfaces:**

***IDrawable:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    public interface IDrawable
    {
        Point Location { get; set; }
        Size Size { get; set; }
        Rectangle GetRealRect(Point origin);
        void Draw(Graphics gfxApi, Point origin);
    }
}
```

***IGUIContainer:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    delegate void SelectionChangedHandler(object sender, bool newIsSelected);

    interface IGUIContainer : IUIElement
    {
        IGUIContainer Parent { get; set; }
        List<IGUIContainer> Controls { get; }
        void AddChild(IGUIContainer child);
        bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        event SelectionChangedHandler SelectionChanged;
        IGUIContainer HitTest(Point mouseCoord);
    }
}
```

***UIElement:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    abstract class UIElement : IUIElement
    {
        private Point _location;
        private Size _size;
        private Color _background;
        private Color _foreground;
        private Color _borderColor;
        private int _borderWidth;

        public UIElement()
        {
            _foreground = Color.Black;
            _background = Color.White;
            _borderColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        public Point Location
        {
            get
            {
                return _location;
            }
            set
            {
                _location = value;
            }
        }

        public Size Size
        {
            get
            {
                return _size;
            }
            set
            {
                _size = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Draw(Graphics drawingApi, Point origin)
        {

            Rectangle inside = GetRealRect(origin);

            Pen borderPen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(_borderColor), _borderWidth);
            drawingApi.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_background), inside);
            drawingApi.DrawRectangle(borderPen, inside);
        }

        public Rectangle ClientRect
        {
            get
            {
                return new Rectangle(_location, _size);
            }
        }


        public Color Background
        {
            get
            {
                return _background;
            }
            set
            {
                _background = value;
            }
        }

        public Color Foreground
        {
            get
            {
                return _foreground;
            }
            set
            {
                _foreground = value;
            }
        }


        public Rectangle GetRealRect(Point origin)
        {
            int left = ClientRect.Left + origin.X;
            int top = ClientRect.Top + origin.Y;
            int width = ClientRect.Width;
            int height = ClientRect.Height;

            Debug.WriteLine("GetRealRect " + left + ", " + top + ", " + width + ", " + height);

            return new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
        }


        public int BorderWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return _borderWidth;
            }
            set
            {
                _borderWidth = value;
            }
        }

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get
            {
                return _borderColor;
            }
            set
            {
                _borderColor = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***GUIControl:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    class GUIControl : UIElement, IGUIContainer
    {
        private IGUIContainer _parent;
        private List<IGUIContainer> _controls = new List<IGUIContainer>();
        private bool _isSelected;

        public List<IGUIContainer> Controls
        {
            get
            {
                return _controls;
            }
        }

        public override void Draw(Graphics api, Point origin)
        {
            Point original = origin;

            base.Draw(api, origin);

            origin.Offset(this.Location);

            foreach (var ctrl in Controls)
            {
                ctrl.Draw(api, origin);
            }

            if (IsSelected)
            {
                Pen selection = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 3);
                selection.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
                api.DrawRectangle(selection, GetRealRect(original));
            }

        }

        public IGUIContainer HitTest(Point coord)
        {
            Point newOrigin = coord;
            newOrigin.Offset(-this.Location.X, -this.Location.Y);

            foreach (var ctrl in Controls)
            {
                IGUIContainer hit = ctrl.HitTest(newOrigin);
                if (hit != null)
                {
                    return hit;
                }
            }

            return ClientRect.Contains(coord) ? this : null;
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;

                if (SelectionChanged != null)
                {
                    SelectionChanged(this, _isSelected);
                }
            }
        }

        public event SelectionChangedHandler SelectionChanged;

        public void AddChild(IGUIContainer child)
        {
            // if you need to implement event propagation this is the place to attach them to children
            child.Parent = this;
            Controls.Add(child);
        }

        public IGUIContainer Parent
        {
            get
            {
                return _parent;
            }
            set
            {
                _parent = value;
            }
        }

        public static IGUIContainer Next(IGUIContainer self)
        {
            if (self.Parent != null &&
                self.Parent.Controls.Count - 1 > self.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(self))
            {
                return self.Parent.Controls[self.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(self) + 1];
            }
            else if (self.Parent != null)
            {
                return Next(self.Parent);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***GUILabel:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    class GuiLabel : GUIControl
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Font Font { get; set; }

        public GuiLabel()
        {
            Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Tahoma"), 12, FontStyle.Regular);            
        }

        public override void Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics api, System.Drawing.Point origin)
        {
            base.Draw(api, origin);

            Rectangle controlRect = GetRealRect(origin);
            SizeF size = api.MeasureString(Text, Font);

            Point textPosition = new Point(controlRect.Location.X + (int)(controlRect.Width - size.Width) / 2,
                                        controlRect.Location.Y + (int)(controlRect.Height - size.Height) / 2);

            api.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(Foreground), textPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

***Extension (for Traverse method to flatten recursion):***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomGUI
{
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> fnRecurse)
        {

            foreach (T item in source)
            {

                yield return item;

                IEnumerable<T> seqRecurse = fnRecurse(item);

                if (seqRecurse != null)
                {

                    foreach (T itemRecurse in Traverse(seqRecurse, fnRecurse))
                    {

                        yield return itemRecurse;

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that is one question that can be answered in a million ways... :)

But as long as you can draw pixels (or anything remotely like it), you can draw a GUI. If you have an object oriented language at hand, I would not choose to highlight and unhighlight the current object. I would give if focus and remove focus from it, and let the object itself decide whether it should be redrawn and how that should be done.

You can automatically unfocus the previous object if all object are placed in some sort of container. When you press a navigational key (like Tab) or press a mouse button, that container can process that message and focus the next object and unfocus the last object.

It requires some programming, but the concept is quite easy. It becomes harder when you want it to perform well, look slick, have all kinds of anumations and transitions... But as I said, the concept is simple and you won't even need OO to do it, although it will probably give you a much cleaner result. I think I can program an ASCII based GUI in DOS Batch on a rainy afternoon if I needed to.